# Arial is substituting with Segoe UI

Tags: debian, xfce, fontconfig, evince

Here are screenshots of Evince's `Properties->Fonts` tab within the same documents:
[image: Arial as Segoe UI]
[image: Still Arial Bold]

It's said that `Arial` is substituting with `Segoe UI`, but `Arial Bold` is still `Arial Bold`.

Output of `fc-match` and `fc-list`:

```
$ fc-match -s "Arial"   
Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Normal"
SegoeUI.ttf: "Segoe UI" "Normal"
SegoeUI-Semilight.ttf: "Segoe UI" "Semilight"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Oblique"
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold Oblique"
Tahoma.ttf: "Tahoma" "Normal"
Verdana.ttf: "Verdana" "Normal"
FreeSans.ttf: "FreeSans" "нормален"
FreeSansBold.ttf: "FreeSans" "получерен"
$ fc-list |grep Arial
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf: Arial:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,thường,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-NarrowBoldItalic.ttf: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Bold Italic,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-Italic.ttf: Arial:style=Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,nghiêng,Etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-Bold.ttf: Arial:style=Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,đậm,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-NarrowBold.ttf: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow Bold,Negreta,tučné,fed,Fett,Έντονα,Bold,Negrita,Lihavoitu,Gras,Félkövér,Grassetto,Vet,Halvfet,Pogrubiony,Negrito,Полужирный,Fet,Kalın,Krepko,Lodia
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-Narrow.ttf: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Regular,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-BoldItalic.ttf: Arial:style=Bold Italic,Negreta cursiva,tučné kurzíva,fed kursiv,Fett Kursiv,Έντονα Πλάγια,Negrita Cursiva,Lihavoitu Kursivoi,Gras Italique,Félkövér dőlt,Grassetto Corsivo,Vet Cursief,Halvfet Kursiv,Pogrubiona kursywa,Negrito Itálico,Полужирный Курсив,Tučná kurzíva,Fet Kursiv,Kalın İtalik,Krepko poševno,nghiêng đậm,Lodi etzana
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial-NarrowItalic.ttf: Arial,Arial Narrow:style=Narrow Italic,Cursiva,kurzíva,kursiv,Πλάγια,Italic,Kursivoitu,Italique,Dőlt,Corsivo,Cursief,Kursywa,Itálico,Курсив,İtalik,Poševno,Etzana
```

> My question is how to use default Arial, not substituted with `Segoe UI`

My system:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch) with 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Evince version 3.22.1
fontconfig version 2.11.0-6.7+b1
Desktop environment: XFCE with compton as compositor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion about `evince doesn't display the correct font` and a small fix on [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/132417/comments/24).

Add the following contents to your `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```
<!-- 
    Stop Arial from being aliased by Segoe UI in Evince
    But seems alias to Helvetica Neue
-->
<alias binding="same">
  <family>ArialMT</family>
  <default>
    <family>Arial</family>
  </default>
</alias>
```